# AttributeError: object has no attribute '_output_tensor_cache'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm trying to do a sentiment analysis classifier based on the [rotten tomatoes dataset](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/b5idqk/p_dataset_480000_rotten_tomatoes_reviews_for_nlp/). I'm getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'RNN' object has no attribute '_output_tensor_cache'

Unfortunately, there isn't help anywhere. I have no idea where to even look.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Embedding, Dense
import os
os.chdir('/home/nicolas/Documents/datasets')

df = pd.read_csv('rotten_tomatoes_reviews.csv', nrows=50_000)

df = df.loc[df.Review.str.len() >= 3]

array = df.Review.values
target = df.Freshness.values

tokenizer = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(num_words=3_000)

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(array)
vector = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(array)

padded = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(vector, maxlen=40)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(padded, target, test_size=2e-1)


class RNN(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        self.rnn1 = LSTM(8, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
        self.rnn2 = LSTM(8)
        self.emb1 = Embedding(input_dim=3_000, output_dim=50, input_length=40)
        self.flc1 = Dense(2)

    def __call__(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        x = self.emb1(inputs)
        x = self.rnn1(x)
        x = self.rnn2(x)
        out = self.flc1(x)
        print(out.shape)
        return out


def main():
    model = RNN()

    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
                  loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=10,
              validation_data=[X_test, y_test], verbose=1)

    scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=16, verbose=1)
    print("Final test loss and accuracy :", scores)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are mixing native Keras implementation and TensorFlow implementation of Keras (i.e. `tf.keras`):

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import Model     # Wrong! DON'T mix keras and tf.keras!
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Embedding, Dense
```

You should **never** do that. Fix the import for `Model` class by using: `from tensorflow.keras import Model`